# how to fill selected values into Checkboxlist from gridview edit options in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

[image]

Please refer the uploaded image which got when I run my web application.

Now i want to edit the values which i select from gridview and fill given checkboklist control with only checked items which is in database.

For example when I click <kbd>edit</kbd> for the item whose id is 5, it has 2 values "Yellow" and "Brown", so now only that values in checkboxlist control should be checked.

Comment: How those options are stored? as one string?

Comment: @anouar.bag : yes ,  stored in one string using commas separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string colors = "Yellow,Brown";
        string[] col = colors.Split(',');
        foreach (ListItem lst in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= col.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (lst.Text == col[i])
                {
                    lst.Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here `string colors` is your string which holds the comma seperated values .